# Flow type checking performance in VSCode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, flowtype

I've built a new project using `create-react-app` and wanted to start it using a static type checking, there are two choices now in market:

- TypeScript
- Flow

I kind want to go with Flow just because it's also built by Facebook and should(?) have better support for a React project.

So what I'm struggling it is type-checking performance in VSCode. Once I created my project, I ran the following commands:

1. `yarn add -D eslint-plugin-prettier husky prettier pretty-quick babel-eslint eslint-plugin-flowtype flow-bin eslint`
2. Added Airbnb React style: `eslint --init`
3. Ran `flow init`
4. Installed [Flow Language Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=flowtype.flow-for-vscode)
5. Disabled JavaScript and TypeScript language support as recommended
6. Added following config to my Workspace settings:

-

```
{
  "flow.useNPMPackagedFlow": true,
  "flow.pathToFlow": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/flow"
}
```

My `.eslintrc` is as follows:

```
{
  "extends": ["airbnb", "plugin:flowtype/recommended"],
  "plugins": ["prettier", "flowtype"],
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true,
    "jest": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"] }],
    "prettier/prettier": [
      "error",
      {
        "printWidth": 80,
        "singleQuote": true,
        "useTabs": false,
        "tabWidth": 2,
        "semi": true,
        "bracketSpacing": true
      }
    ]
  },
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "paths": ["src"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However Flow seems to be quite slow on my machine, I have added a simple function to my `App.js`:

```
const sum = (a: number, b: number) => a + b;
sum(1, '12323');
```

And it takes up to 10 seconds to validate my code which is quite a bummer. Is there a way to speed this up?

Maybe it's worth to start with TypeScript and don't bother with Flow?

Comment: One thing to consider: VSCode plugins don't clean up after themselves when you quit VSCode. Check for zombie flow processes with `ps aux | grep flow` in a terminal

Comment: Flow has a long history of unsolvable memory problems: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2152 but no one knows why

Comment: @AndyRay forgot to mention that I'm running on Windows. There are few flow processes running but just one of them has reached 100mb and my machine has 16gb of ram, which is more than enough. Or isn't it?

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas what did you finally go with and why? A little help needed.

Comment: @itaintme went with TypeScript. Accepted answer is still very valid and has exact reasons :)

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas could you get hot reloading to work with TS + expo? It seems to load the complete app again each time for me.

Comment: I couldn't :| @itaintme

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas I found a way. Needed to disable `live reload` first before enabling `hot reload` for it to work properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some open issues regarding possible memory leaks and performance related problems with flow, some links below:

https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2152

https://github.com/flowtype/flow-bin/issues/70

Both tools are great and have their pros and cons, I would personally recommend to give a try to TypeScript too and perform a comparison yourself.

In my own experience on a large code base I have found TypeScript:

- more performant
- more types for external libraries
- larger community

Comment: It seems that I'll give a try to TS. It seems to be in a better shape currently. Thanks!